# what would return for back() method for an empty string?

Tags: c++, string

In C++ given an empty string, what would .back() method return? I met different behavior. One is returning an empty string, one is undefined behavior. Is it depending on compiler ? Could anybody advise?

Comment: You don't seem to have a clear understanding of what "undefined behavior" means, if you say you only saw it in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [`std::string::back`documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back). It clearly states what happens in this case.

> Returns reference to the last character in the string. The behavior is undefined if empty() == true.

In other words, you should expect *undefined behavior* which means whatever your compiler gives you is the *right result* **and you can't rely on the result**.

Comment: Downvote? If you'd explain the issue with the answer I'd be happy to improve it.

Comment: the odds the downvoter will see that are next to zero: imagine standing next to litter on the street and asking "who dropped this?  What could I do to stop it?" at every passer-by.  And anyone who has a habit of responding to that kind of comment asking for downvote justification has experienced lots of "downvoted rage" in return.  You might not: but the work to determine that is large, for little return.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I didn't expect to get feedback. However, I was genuinely curious to know if there is something _wrong_ with the answer. I figured it was worth a shot since I commented shortly after the downvote occurred.